# counting time while activity is not visible

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

My app needs to count time from the moment the user clicks a button and until he clicks it again. The user should be able to "walk around" other apps and activities and when he opens my app again - the counter will keep counting steady.

Right now I have the counter running in the background with an AsyncTask but when the user "Walks around" and fiddle with other apps and activities and then come back - my app is not counting. It's like you've started the app for the first time.

What do I need to do in order to make it keep working and counting while in the background and through the activity lifecycle?

thanks

Comment: Why not store the time when it was clicked, then when it's clicked again just calculate the difference?

Comment: I can do it but thats not what I want. I want the user to have the counter running when he opens the app again and also learn how to do it for different scenerios

Comment: If you are using the `Back Button` to return to the launcher your application will be destroyed, so it will need to be recreated when you think you are resuming it.  If you `Override` the activity lifecycle events and log a message you can track what happens.  Using a `Service` will still require some form of background task if you want to send/log anythying every second, it will not do it on its own.  Personally I would just get it to keep a start and stop time and do as @Nick says and look out for time changes.  Plus there are other things wrong with @jucas answer but I'm out of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not record the time your count begins and subtract it from the time your app reappears and then use that value resume whatever dynamic counting task your display has to accomplish?

ex:
1. user starts app at 000 secs. sys timestamp in millisecs is 11100000 (or whatever)
2. app runs for 5 seconds.
3. user opens their email app, etc.
4. after 20 seconds the user resumes the timer app.
5. app calculates offset; 11100025 -11100000 = 25.
6. app resumes "tick" at 25.

Comment: because it sounds like a hack... besides I want to learn WHY my method of doing it doesn't work and what is the right way.

What if it was a different task that had to run in the background and still pick up where it left from? there must be a way to do it that I just need to learn.

Comment: Its not a hack - its actually the most efficient way possible to do this kind of thing and is how any good timer app works.  Using a background thread uses more memory, cpu time, is more vulnerable to the device lagging, crashing, being turned off etc. It also wastes battery life. If the task was anything other than a timer it might make sense to use a background task

Comment: As far as why your async task isnt working properly, can you post your code on how you create the task?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I appreciate it. I will make the changes.

Comment: From developers blog: System.currentTimeMillis() is the standard "wall" clock (time and date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)), so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application. Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock.

Comment: If you are using System.currentTimeMillis(), consider listening to the ACTION_TIME_TICK, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.

Comment: Basically that means you can (and personally id even say should) use System.currentTimeMillis() but if you want to be safe, listen for those events to make sure that the clock is not changed while your timer is running.  If you get one of those events while its running, then you know your timer may be invalid.

Comment: Another option would be to use System.ellapsedRealtime().  For a pure stopwatch app this might be a better choice as it is unaffected by the user/network adjusting its clock.  For an alarm clock app that simply needs to show a dynamic countdown I don't like this as much because the value cannot be serialized to survive system crashes.

Comment: Also note that while a timezone could change, because System.currentTimeMillis is milliseconds from an epoch, it's immune to such changes.  I'm not really sure why they include ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED in their warning.

Comment: It's an arbitrary date in history.  For Android devices, it's Jan 1st, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.  Epoch time is simply the difference between "now" and the epoch, or in the case of System.curentTimeMillis(), the number of milliseconds that have ellapsed since Jan 1, 1970.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do this, use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Your usage should be like this, when you want to start counting you create an intent on your activity to start your service, on the service you start sending a broadcast every second or so that you would receive on your activity.

You will have to implement a broadcastreceiver on your activity, and register and unregister it on the onResume and onPause methods.

After the user has clicked again on your button then send a broadcast/intent from your Activity to your service telling it to stop counting.

The service is not bound to your activity's lifecycle, and it will run as long as it doesn't receive the broadcast/intent telling it to stop.

Comment: thank you very much this is what I was looking for. A proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple you need a service which counts whatever you need to count.